# Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token

Tags: android, compiler-warnings, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am trying to implement a simple android facebook login but facebook credential popup is not opening and `Logcat` is showing this warning

```
 Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.
```

I have already added application ID to `manifest file` :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Additionally I would like you all to suggest me some good tutorial for android facebook login which would redirect to my app's page  after authentication and fetching some user information as whatever tutorial I found on internet contains a lot of extra information.

Thanks in advance..